# Pandoc filter tikz.py returns "not a valid json value"

Tags: json, python-2.7, markdown, pandoc, tikz

I'm using the tikz.py pandocfilter to turn latex tikz code in a markdown file into images in the output html file. I'm running pandoc version 1.17.0.2, python 2.7.10 and ImageMagick 6.9.6-4. My pandoc command is:

```
pandoc -s -c --mathjax -i- t slidy tik.md --filter tikz.py -o tik.html
```

(but I've tried simpler commands without slidy or mathjax and they give the same issue)

Where tik.md contains a simple tikz environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

tikz.py runs well and it seems to successfully generate the image:

> $ pandoc -s -c --mathjax -i -t slidy tik.md --filter tikz.py -o tik.html
>
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) 
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled.
>
> entering extended mode
>
> (./tikz.tex
>
> LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
>
> Babel ...
>
> .....
>
> [1] (./tikz.aux) )
>
> Output written on tikz.pdf (1 page, 1077 bytes).
>
> Transcript written on tikz.log.
>
> Created image tikz-images/53200b26dfa2c05d2b92647ef74211f7a2ce0c0e.png
>
> pandoc: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value

I am using an unaltered tikz.py so it is not clear to me where the source of the problem could be. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same thing in a Ruby filter, and finally figured out that it was because I was trying to write debugging output to standard output. Since a filter has to read standard input and write to standard output, any debugging output on standard output will blow things up.

In my Ruby filter I had to change `puts 'debug stuff'` to `STDERR.puts 'debug stuff'`.